# why the boolean variable isn't being assigned true?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

Even if I enter '1234', accountAccess still remains False, so the program keeps asking for password. I know there might be hundred other ways to do it, but I'm kinda new to Python, so I'm exploring the possibilities. Sorry if it's a noob question :3

```
password = 1234
accountAccess = False
print("___Welcome to ATM___")
while accountAccess == False:
    userInput = input("Enter password: ")
    if userInput == password:
        accountAccess = True
if accountAccess == True:
    print("Permission granted!")
```

Comment: Your password is an **integer** it will never be equal to any **string** the user gives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to the following:

```
password = "1234"
```

`input` returns a `string`, not an `int`